# JavaScript performance difference with time(int) declaration?

Tags: javascript

What it is the difference in having:

```
setInterval(function(){

},5000);
```

and:

```
setInterval(function(){

},5E3);
```

I know that `5E3` is like saying `5*1000` but is there is any benefits one from another way to declare times?

Comment: The **major difference is readability**. Every developer would immediately know that the first one is 5 seconds while some thinking may be involved with the second one. Don't obfuscate your code in this way as you make it less maintainable.

Comment: why minifier do 50000 to 5e3, just less file size ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no difference, as both literals are parsed into the same primitive number.

Comment: what about space? it is 1bit smaller to have `5E3`

Comment: Not even. Most of the times, resources are sent compressed. It's possible 5000 compresses better than 5E3 (in fact it depends on the rest of the file).